# Blank Page after clicking button android eclipse?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, button

I thought I did everything right but when I click the button I get a blank page instead of a page with a text. I want that the creation.xml comes up after clicking the button on the main xml. What did I wrong ?

My main activity xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/creeper" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="@string/hello"
android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:text="@string/button1_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My main activity java

```
package com.berkcoop.deneme;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button1, button2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);




button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Creation.class);
startActivity(intent1);


}
});

}
```

My creation xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:text="Creations"
android:textSize="25sp"
android:gravity="center"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.berkcoop.deneme"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
android:name="com.berkcoop.deneme.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.berkcoop.deneme.Creation"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and my creation java

```
package com.berkcoop.deneme;

import android.app.Activity;

public class Creation extends Activity{

@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.setContentView(R.layout.creation);
}

}
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Why do you override the `setContentView` method in your Creation class? Since you don't call it, it won't set the correct view.

You should call `setContentView` from `onCreate`, and as far as I know, there is no need to override `setContentView`.

Try this in Creation:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.creation);
}
```